# Having More than one primary key in sq lite db

Tags: android, sqlite

I m trying to develop android app to storing some data to sqlite db.for that i have used below code, my problem is that i want three columns to be primary keys.but i dont know how to do it with these code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_PCODE + " TEXT NOT NULL , "+
            KEY_STATE + " TEXT NOT NULL , "+
            KEY_COUNT + " TEXT); "
    );
}
```

Comment: `Primary Key (Row1, Row2, Row3);`

Answer (score 0):

the sintax is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (column1 TEXT NOT NULL, 
  column2 TEXT NOT NULL, 
  column3 TEXT NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2));
```

Comment: @Pals The syntax is right; the column type is declared in the lines above. (And SQLite doesn't need a data type anyway.)

Comment: @CL it's after the edit. At first it was just simple example of the sintax.